# Proof with sets

Tags: elementary-number-theory, elementary-set-theory, proof-verification

I managed to write this out in english but not sure how to prove it

```
∀x ∈ N[(∃y ∈ N (2 <= y ^ y < x ^ y | x )) -> (∃z ∈ N(2<= z ^ z <= sqrt(x) ^ z | x))]
```

My answer so far: For all x where x is a natural number, for some y is an element of natural numbers, y is greater than or equal to 2 and y is less than x and y divides x, that implies for some z is an element of natural numbers where z is greater than or equal to 2 and z is less than or equal to the square root of x and z divides x.

Comment: If $x = yy'$, then at least one of the numbers $y$ and $y'$ must be $\leq \sqrt{x}$.

Comment: A proper translation into English might rather be: "Every composite natural number $x$ has a proper divisor not larger than the square root of $x$"

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen how would I prove this statement ?

Comment: the "^" mentioned in my statement is actually an upside down V

Comment: As an aside, [this page](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) will teach you how to use MathJax and $\LaTeX$ on this site so you can write things like $\forall x \in \Bbb N~[(\exists y\in \Bbb N~(2\leq y~\wedge~ y<x~\wedge~ y\mid x))\implies\dots$

Comment: @JMoravitz thank you :) !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We want to prove
$$\tag0\forall x\in\Bbb N[(\exists y\in \Bbb N(2\le y\land y<x\land y\mid x))\to (\exists z\in \Bbb N(2\le z\land z\le \sqrt x\land z\mid x))]. $$
So let $x\in\Bbb N$ be arbitrary. For this $x$, we want to prove 
$$\tag1(\exists y\in \Bbb N(2\le y\land y<x\land y\mid x))\to (\exists z\in \Bbb N(2\le z\land z\le \sqrt x\land z\mid x)).$$
So assume $$\tag2\exists y\in \Bbb N(2\le y\land y<x\land y\mid x).$$ Accordingly, let $u\in\Bbb N$ be such that $2\le u\land u<x\land u\mid x$. Recall that $u\mid x$ means that $x=uv$ for some $v\in\Bbb N$.
As this also means $x=vu$, we conclude that $v\mid x$.
Also, $v>1$ as otherwise we would have $x=u\cdot 1=u$. contradicting $u<x$.
Note that $v>1$ is equivalent to $v\ge 2$ because $v\in\Bbb N$.
Assume for the moment that both $u>\sqrt x$ and $v>\sqrt x$.
Then $uv>\sqrt x\cdot\sqrt x=x$ (careful: We make use of $x>0$ here!), contradicting $x=uv$.
We conclude that we cannot have both $u>\sqrt x$ and $v>\sqrt x$.
In other words, $u\le \sqrt x$ or $v\le sqrt x$.
In the first case, $2\le u\land u\le \sqrt x\land u\mid x$, in the second case
$2\le v\land v\le \sqrt x\land v\mid x$.
At any rate, 
$$\tag3\exists z\in \Bbb N(2\le z\land z\le \sqrt x\land z\mid x). $$
Thus we have proved $(3)$ from the assumption $(2)$. In other words, we have proved $(1)$.
As we did so for arbitrary $x\in\Bbb N$, we actually showed $(0)$.

Comment: Seems like a complicated approach